# how to scan nearby BLE devices only

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to Scan nearby BLE devices in which my device is [MOTO E phone](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_e-6376.php) and my nearby BLE devices are [CSR 8670 dev Kit](http://www.csr.com/products/63/csr8670) ,also NOKIA 525 and MOTO G.But its not even scanning a single device even all of these devices are BLE compatible. I am using the below link as my reference to scan my BLE devices :-

http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/DeviceScanActivity.html

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"/>
        <service android:name=".BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Scanning device**

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable)
    {
     if (enable) 
    {
      // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

Comment: None of those devices are BLE peripherals, which is what you're scanning for. The CSR devkit is BT3 with audio-profiles, **not** a BLE device. The other two devices are able to be BLE masters, but are not peripherals. I don't think Bluez lets you put an Android device into BLE peripheral mode.

Comment: Thanks your answer really help me and shown me the right path . But the devKit I am using is suitable For both end ,in audio-profiles and also in BLE device.

Comment: That's great if it is -- you'll need to configure it as a BLE peripheral though. I've had great success with Nordic's chips.